# What does /* at end of file path mean for chmod?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm following a guide for installing tomcat on ubuntu, and I'm stuck on a step which is to run the following command:

```
sudo chmod g+r conf/*
```

What does the `/*` mean? Does it mean make the change for all files in the `/conf` folder? When I run the command, I get the following error:

```
chmod: cannot access 'conf/*': No such file or directory
```

This is what the folder looks like:

```
bin  conf  lib  LICENSE  logs  ...
```

So the `/conf` folder is in there - other commands I run on the folder work ok:

```
sudo chgrp -R tomcat conf
sudo chmod g+rwx conf
```

The guide [is here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I'm at "Step 4: Update Permissions".

Here is an `ls -la` of the `/opt/tomcat` folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root    4096 Aug 15 03:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Aug 15 03:14 ..
drwxr-x--- 2 root root    4096 Aug 15 03:15 bin
drwxrwx--- 2 root tomcat  4096 Jul  6 08:45 conf
drwxr-x--- 2 root root    4096 Aug 15 03:15 lib
-rw-r----- 1 root root   57092 Jul  6 08:45 LICENSE
drwxr-x--- 2 root root    4096 Jul  6 08:43 logs
-rw-r----- 1 root root    1723 Jul  6 08:45 NOTICE
-rw-r----- 1 root root    7063 Jul  6 08:45 RELEASE-NOTES
-rw-r----- 1 root root   15946 Jul  6 08:45 RUNNING.txt
drwxr-x--- 2 root root    4096 Aug 15 03:15 temp
drwxr-x--- 7 root root    4096 Jul  6 08:44 webapps
drwxr-x--- 2 root root    4096 Jul  6 08:43 work
```

and these are the files that are in the /conf folder:

```
sudo ls -al conf/
-rw------- 1 root tomcat  12502 Jul  6 08:45 catalina.policy
-rw------- 1 root tomcat   7203 Jul  6 08:45 catalina.properties
-rw------- 1 root tomcat   1338 Jul  6 08:45 context.xml
-rw------- 1 root tomcat   1149 Jul  6 08:45 jaspic-providers.xml
-rw------- 1 root tomcat   2358 Jul  6 08:45 jaspic-providers.xsd
-rw------- 1 root tomcat   3622 Jul  6 08:45 logging.properties
-rw------- 1 root tomcat   7283 Jul  6 08:45 server.xml
-rw------- 1 root tomcat   2164 Jul  6 08:45 tomcat-users.xml
-rw------- 1 root tomcat   2633 Jul  6 08:45 tomcat-users.xsd
-rw------- 1 root tomcat 168577 Jul  6 08:45 web.xml
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the guide you are using? Also could you do an `ls -la` on the directory rather than just an `ls`

Comment: how about `sudo chmod g+r ./conf/*`  or `sudo chmod -R g+r ./conf` ? if those don't work, confirm your pwd.

Comment: @Frank Thomas the [sudo chmod -R g+r ./conf] option worked - do you know why that might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are not in the `tomcat` group while running the commands.  The problem here is that the `*` glob is going to be expanded by your shell before executing `sudo` so it will be expanding it as your current user.  If that user is not in the `tomcat` directory it has no permission to list the files in `conf`, and so the glob fails to expand, which usually means you get the string back unchanged, then you try the `sudo` command, but glob expansion is already done, so it is looking for a file literally named `conf/*` which clearly does not exist.

So you could either use a user who has permission in that directory, or you could have `sudo` run a command that will defer the glob expansion like

```
sudo sh -c "chmod g+r conf/*"
```

so the glob will be expanded after `sudo` has given you elevated permissions

To answer your question of "what does it mean," as I mentioned above the `*` is a glob character for shells.  You can read a lot about it [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html).  It's a way to match lots of files without having to specifically enumerate them by hand.  You just specify patterns that will match the names you want, and `*` basically means "pretty much anything any number of times"

Since order of operations seems to be important to this question, [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/intro) is a page that talks about the order in which different expansions happen in the shell (at least `bash` but most are similar).  All that happens before the command is executed, so it all happens before `sudo` is invoked in this specific situation.

Comment: Oh I see - yeah when I run the "groups" command, I only get back "testuser sudo" (testuser is my original group). So this user is not part of group "tomcat". Your recommended workaround command works, even though I am not part of the group. I added my user to the tomcat group afterwards as a test, and then the original command  finally works, glorious!

Comment: Shell expansion is the key. I didn't know in the past that when we put `*` , it is actually shell that finds every matching item and virtually adds it to argument list.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @Eric Renoufs answer you can give shell access to tomcat8 user by using this command

```
$ sudo -s -u <tomcat user> then issue
$ chmod g+r conf/*
```

[This link directed me to this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/595088/why-does-sudo-su-su-tomcat-doesnt-switch-to-tomcat-user)